# Should I put getStaticProps to redux store?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I have a question. Can I put data from getStaticProps to redux? I think it is the only way to deal with data in DB and on the client-side, because, for example when I delete data on the page it deletes in database but not on website

```
const Home: NextPage = (
  props: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>
) => {
  return <MainPage assets={props.assets} />;
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const assetsId = await getDataFromMongo();

  const promises = assetsId.map(async (id: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/assets/${id}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CoinAPI-Key": "key",
      },
    });
    return await response.json();
  });

  return {
    props: {
      assets: (await Promise.all(promises)).flat(),
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};
```